# How to pack a Togl widget (using Tcl script) underneath a Tkinter Frame?

Tags: tkinter, tcl, pyopengl

I am working on a project which requires me to build a Tkinter UI, with a high demanding graphical display.

After several trails, I have decided to use pyOpenGL(Togl) for graphical rendering.
Note that because of performance issues, I have decided to run OpenGL in C++ instead of using the pyOpenGL wrapper in Python.

My problem is, seems like Togl in display.tcl doesn't recognize the wid which I sent from Tkinter. Instead, display.tcl will create a new Togl widget named with given wid.

Can anyone help me on this?

Moreover, is there a better way to due with high demanding graphical display with Tkinter UI.

In Tkinter UI:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk

class Layout(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.Frame = tk.Frame(self, relief=tk.RAISED, container = "True")
        self.Frame.grid()
        top = Toplevel(use=self.Frame.winfo_id())

        self.display = tk.Tk()
        self.display.tk.eval("source {/path/display.tcl}')
        self.display.tk.eval('setup ' + str(top.winfo_pathname(top.winfo_id())) )
```

In display.tcl

```
load [file dirname [info script]]/display[info sharedlibextension]

proc setup {wid} 
{
     display $wid
}

proc newRot {wid} 
{
    togl $wid -width 200 -height 200  -rgba true  -double true  -depth true
    pack $wid -expand true -fill both
}
```

Comment: That's Tcl script has significant syntactic problems as written (the `{` starting the procedure bodies should be at the end of the preceding line). Are you getting any errors or exceptions?